# Updating a column in excel

Tags: excel

I have two excel sheets with one column common for both. I need to match the column value and update the next column by following the excel 2.

for example:

I have excel1 as

```
   A                 B        C          D
fruits              22     f.market 
vegetables          50     v.market
flowers             60     l.market
```

excel2

```
  A          B
fruits      1000
flowers     2000
```

So, I need to update column D in excel 1 as 1000 where column A is fruits

Comment: Have you considered using VLOOKUP or possibly an INDEX/MATCH combination?

Comment: VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH anything would be fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use VLOOKUP() for fetching the respective value. Considering your data value 'fruits' is in cell A1 try to use following function

=VLOOKUP(A1,$A1$B2,2,false)